# How to get 10 records from child in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Can anyone please help me.I have two domains.

```
Class Parent{
      static hasMany = [child: Child];
}

Class Child{

}
```

In database there are 20 records.I want to get 10 records only without refreshing the page.So i used **remote pagination** like.

gsp code is

```
<util:remotePaginate controller="Parent" action="show"   
       total="${parentList.size()}"
                               update="updatedListId" max="10" pageSizes="[10, 20, 50,100]"/>
```

In Controller i wrote like.

```
 def parent =Parent.get(1);
 def parentList =  parent.getChild();
```

I tried this one but its is not working.

```
 def childs = Child.findAllByParent(parent, [max: 10])
```

It is giving all records but i need to here get only 10 records. I set params max value and pass it as argument but its not working.

please help me.
thanks

Comment: The `Child` knows who is his `Parent`? Try adding a `static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]` in your `Child` class

Comment: is it possible without belongsTo

Answer (score 0):

You can get the childs in a join via HQL:

```
 Child.executeQuery("select c from Parent p join p.childs c where p=:p", [p:p, max:10])
```

Comment: i am getting error like No property found for name [parent] for class [class com.myapp.model.Child]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `where` query?

```
// Parent.groovy
class Parent{
    static hasMany = [ children: Child ]
}

// Where query in controller/service
Parent.where { id == 1L }.children.list(max: 10)
```